# 2 arrays increasing in a specific way

Tags: vba

I need two arrays in VBA language thay will create the following values

```
1  2
1  3
1  4
2  3
2  4
3  4
```

so when 4 is reached in the second array, the next element of array 1 is what it was plus 1 and the next element of array 2 is the next element of array 1 + 1. I  have tried do until loops but I get infinite calculations.

I tried the following but I get infinite calculations

Dim ENumber As Variant
    ENumber = Worksheets("Inter").Range("B1")

```
Dim FirstLoop As Boolean

Dim m As Variant

ReDim IndexofE1(ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) As Variant
ReDim IndexofE2(ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) As Variant

IndexofE1(0) = 1

FirstLoop = True

Do Until IndexofE1(ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) = Enumber - 1

    If IndexofEl2(m) <> ENumber Then

        If FirstLoop = False Then
            IndexofE1(m + 1) = IndexofE1(m)
            IndexofE2(m + 1) = IndexofE1(m) + 1
        End If

        If FirstLoop = True Then IndexofE2(m + 1) = IndexofE1(m) + 1

    Else
        IndexofE1(m + 1) = IndexofE1(m) + 1
        IndexofE2(m + 1) = IndexofE1(m + 1) + 1
    End If

    FirstLoop = False

Loop
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so that we can help.

Comment: Of course you will. When are they supposed to end?

Comment: You never change "ENumber" so if the expression evaluates false, in other words, you enter the loop, it will always do evaluate false == eternal loop. I assume this is what @GuyLowe meant :)

Comment: I am new to VBA so I am sorry. This is the first loop I have written. I state when the first array is to stop when the element is equal to Enumber - 1. Can you explicitly write the code. I am new and I have stuck here for a long time

Comment: @Lvassilopoulos In "Do...Loop" cycles you set a boolean expression. This means if you add "Do Until False" it will be an eternal loop, as well as "Do Until True" will never enter the loop. So as long as "Do Until IndexofE1(ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) = Enumber - 1" evaluates false, the cycle will not end and as you do not alter "ENumber" in your loop, it will. You also have a typo ("ENumber" vs "Enumber") so add "Option Explicit" as the very first line of the code and fix any errors afterwards

Comment: Thank you Mark but I do not understand since I am new to programming.

Comment: Okay :D See answers below then. I'd recommend at least trying though. If you don't understand whys and hows and not willing to learn, you'll bump into an issue every two seconds and won't have an idea how to solve them. No offense, just saying. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.  I made one two dimensional array instead of 2 one dimensional arrays.

```
Sub khkljhlkjh()
Dim ENumber As Variant
ENumber = Worksheets("Inter").Range("B1")
Dim IndexofE1
Dim i&, j&

Dim m As Long

ReDim IndexofE1(1 To ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2, 1 To 2) As Variant

m = 1
For i = 1 To ENumber - 1
    For j = i + 1 To ENumber
        IndexofE1(m, 1) = i
        IndexofE1(m, 2) = j
        m = m + 1g
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

If you want the two arrays the:

```
Sub khkljhlkjh()
Dim ENumber As Variant
ENumber = Worksheets("Inter").Range("B1")
Dim IndexofE1
Dim IndexofE2
Dim i&, j&

Dim m As Long

ReDim IndexofE1(1 To ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) As Variant
ReDim IndexofE2(1 To ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) As Variant
m = 1
For i = 1 To ENumber - 1
    For j = i + 1 To ENumber
        IndexofE1(m) = i
        IndexofE2(m) = j
        m = m + 1
    Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Now neither of these do anything with the arrays as your snippet does not show what you want to do with them.  You will need to output the arrays to something so you can see the values.

Comment: nice method name Scott :)

Comment: @Mark the fingers will do what the fingers will do.

Comment: but this way the `IndexofE2` will be the same as `IndexofE1`. I didn't get this was OP's request

Comment: @user3598756 yup mistyped. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you Scott. This is the answer I understand and this is what I chose to use

Comment: @Lvassilopoulos then please mark as correct by clicking check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Dim int1 As Integer, int2 As Integer, intMax As Integer, intRes() As Integer, intIndex As Integer

intMax = 4
ReDim intRes(1 To intMax * (intMax - 1) / 2, 1 To 2)

Do
    int1 = int1 + 1
    If int1 = intMax Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    For int2 = int1 + 1 To intMax
        intIndex = intIndex + 1
        intRes(intIndex, 1) = int1
        intRes(intIndex, 2) = int2


    Next
Loop
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need it in array form only. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

two proposals

a)
this will output two arrays with numbers you shown, although last array position is not used

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim ENumber As Long, currVal1 As Long, i As Long, index As Long
    Dim array1 As Variant, array2 As Variant

    ENumber = Worksheets("Inter").Range("B1")
    ReDim IndexofE1(ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) As Variant
    ReDim IndexofE2(ENumber * (ENumber - 1) / 2) As Variant

    currVal1 = 1
    index = 0
    Do While currVal1 <= ENumber - 1
        For i = currVal1 + 1 To ENumber
            IndexofE1(index) = currVal1
            IndexofE2(index) = i
            index = index + 1
        Next i
        currVal1 = currVal1 + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

b)
this will output two variant arrays with no dimming issues

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim ENumber As Long
    Dim array1 As Variant, array2 As Variant

    ENumber = Worksheets("Inter").Range("B1")

    getArrays ENumber, array1, array2

End Sub

Sub getArrays(ENumber As Long, array1 As Variant, array2 As Variant)
    Dim currVal1 As Long, i As Long
    Dim strng1 As String, strng2 As String

    currVal1 = 1
    Do While currVal1 <= ENumber - 1
        For i = currVal1 + 1 To ENumber
            strng1 = strng1 & currVal1 & " "
            strng2 = strng2 & i & " "
        Next i
        currVal1 = currVal1 + 1
    Loop

    array1 = Split(Left(strng1, Len(strng1) - 1))
    array2 = Split(Left(strng2, Len(strng2) - 1))
End Sub
```